# How group by and get the count in has_many :through rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, orm

Three models

- Tags
- Posts
- PostTags

Tags has many Posts through PostTags

so what i need is to get all the name of tags which has maximum number of posts with the count

Comment: Atleast give us the migration files to see the DB columns :)

Comment: @arup : consider it as very basic thing  
tag => id ,name,  
post => id ,description,   
post_tags => tag_id,post_id

Comment: Which DB client you are using ?

Comment: Does Tag and Post contains many to many relationship ?

Comment: How do you filter the maximum count. What is the maximum value ?

Comment: Yes maximum on which basis?

Comment: @arup please read the question

Comment: @architgupta same with you

Comment: So if you say have maximum number as `10`, and you have 2 tags having maximum value as `10`, then you want to get the 2 tag names.. Am I right ?

Comment: like
arup=> 10
srdp=>8 etc etc

Comment: Ok.. then your line _has maximum number of posts_ is misleading.. :)

Answer (score 4):

As simple as that, it will work for rails 3 and rails 4

```
Post.joins(:tags).group("tags.name").count
```

Answer (score 3):

Following code should satisfy your needs:

```
Tag
  .select('tags.name, COUNT(posts.*) AS posts_count')
  .joins(:posts)
  .order('posts_count DESC')
  .group('tags.name')
  .group_by(&:posts_count)
```

Comment: It is not correct. `Tag` and `Post` don't have direct mapping.

Comment: Yes.. so where you have used the join table ?

Comment: Is it? Ohkay.. I was not aware of. Can you please show the console sql? I didn't aware of. But you are missing `having` clause to filter maximum account.

Comment: @Alexaner let me check it i will get back to you if it doesn't work if it work i will accept the answer

Comment: @SRDP you can add `.group_by(&:posts_count)` to the end of the chain to group your tags by amount of posts if you need the maximum one.